# Why was the percent sign (%) chosen as the format specifier for the printf family of functions?

Tags: c, history

Everyone knows that, at least in C, you use the `printf` family of functions to print a formatted string. And these functions use a [percent sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign) (`%`) to indicate the beginning of a format specifier. For example, `%d` means to print an `int`, and `%u` means to print an `unsigned int`. If you're unfamiliar with how the `printf` function and format placeholders work, or simply need a refresher, [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) is a good place to start.

**My question is, is there a particularly compelling reason why this was originally or should be chosen in the future as the format specifier?**

Obviously the decision was made a long time ago (very likely for a predecessor of even the C language), and it's been more or less "standard" ever since then (not only in C, but also in a vast array of other languages that have adopted its syntax to varying degrees), so it's far too late to ever change. But I'm still curious if anyone has any insight on why this choice might have been made in the first place, and whether it still makes sense as the choice if one is designing a new language with similar functionality.

For example, with C# (and the other family of .NET languages), Microsoft made a slightly different decision regarding the operation of the string formatting functions. Although some degree of type safety can be enforced there (unlike with the implementation of `printf` in C), and therefore it is unnecessary to include an indication of the type of the corresponding parameter, they decided to use zero-indexed pairs of curly braces (`{}`) as format specifiers, like so:

```cs
string output = String.Format("In {0}, the temperature is {1} degrees Celsius.",
                              "Texas", 37);
Console.WriteLine(output);

// Output:
//     In Texas, the temperature is 37 degrees Celsius.
```

[The documentation for the `String.Format` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) contains more information, as does [this article on composite formatting in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), but the exact details are rather unimportant. The point is simply that they abandoned the long-standing practice of using `%` to indicate the beginning of a format specifier. The C language could just have easily used `{d}` and `{u}`, but it didn't. Anyone have any thoughts on why, whether this decision makes sense in retrospect, and whether new implementations should follow it?

Obviously there's no character that could be chosen that wouldn't have to be escapable so that it could be included in the string itself, but that problem is quite well solved already by just using *two* of them. What other considerations are relevant?

Comment: The escaping problem is *not* solved by using two characters. It just means you have one more character to escape.

Comment: @Juhana: I think he meant that the escape character itself can be printed by doubling it with `%%`, or include a backslash in a string literal with a double backslash.

Comment: I am curious. Certainly, it would be possible to use `{u}` instead of `%u` but would it have any significant advantage? It seems like a largely arbitrary choice.

Comment: Interesting aside: Python [adopted a similar syntax](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) as well now.

Comment: as to Microsoft not following established customs, it is all about **lock in**, they want people using their tools to get locked into using those tools, if someone learns C# before anything else, the `%` will be the foreign concept. Microsoft wants their tools to be just enough different that you don't want to spend any time learning anything that isn't what you already know.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson so you are saying they deliberately chose the `{}` syntax so that people learning C# would not start learning anything else? I find it very hard to believe that was a major, if even any, part of their design decision. Can you backup your statement somehow?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I also have a hard time believing that.

Comment: MS did it to Java in 1996, they made subtle changes to lock in people to Java that only ran on Windows. It worked, in 2009 I worked on a project for a multi-billion dollar a year company that was Java and would only run on Windows and MS JVM. MS did the same thing with D3D and other things that had perfectly good existing technologies, they subtly pervert them and get lock it. It isn't very ethical but it is good business sense when it works.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - by that logic (that developers would not learn another format string escape sequence), they would *also* be shooting themselves in foot by alienating developers who already knew the `%` convention. Clearly that was not the case.

Comment: I think, the MS's reason was that if they would maintain %0, %1 etc, it would be (1) confusing to the people who come with C background, as % implies %d, %f etc to them; (2) would have serious trouble for representing 10th and further arguments.

Comment: Interestingly, Python abandoned (a much superior form of) [`%` formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) in favour of [something akin to .NET’s `{}` formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) because the latter offers more flexibility.

Comment: Why is the sky blue, and why is the word "blue" named blue? They had to pick something.

Comment: GCC (and, I'm sure, many other compilers) sure support at least what could be called "some degree of type safety" with `printf()` and friends, by inspecting the formatting string and matching the conversion specifiers against the arguments. See the [`format`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bformat_007d-function-attribute-2845) function atttribute.

Comment: @CharlesBailey There is big difference between `%u`  and `{u}` in parsing. With just 1 char prefix it's much simpler to parse - which made sense back in times where every byte was expensive.

Comment: @Agent_L: Intuitively, quite the opposite. With `{...}` syntax, you parse to the next `}` character. With `%...`, you need to parse to the next of `d`, `i`, `u`, `f`, ..... Then, some type designators can be uppercase or lowercase, in fact making for distinct designators (`%g` -> lower case floating point, possibly in exponential notation, `%G` -> same, but uppercase). But that's not all, with flags, width, justification and precision, a simple `%d` can become `%-6.3hhd` after some tweaking, and that "big" difference becomes negligible. ...

Comment: ... @Agent_L: All in all, it looks like you didn't know that format string terms can be more complex; that, or you are not very firm in parser construction (in which case you shouldn't claim such things). Format string terms are not "just 1 char prefix", there can be several, actually. And the parser needs at least one lookahead in order to differentiate `h` and `hh`.

Comment: @phresnel All in all, it looks like you've taken my comment, added own misconceptions and answered to those misconceptions mostly. "1 char prefix" refers to "%" alone, not whole format specifier. You also don't seem to be very firm in parser construction if you try to think about them "intuitively" rather than "mechanically". A closing char helps nothing, "not in a list of allowed control chars" is just as good ending signal as "closing char". It's only easier on humans. `printf` parser doesn't need lookahead, encountering 'h' fires subroutine that parses next char, that's all.

Comment: @Agent_L: You were concerned about parsing simplicity and byte cost (for whatever definition of byte cost). Then you proceed to state that "not in a list of allowed control chars" is just as good as "closing char".  But if every byte is important, how is `if (c != 'd' && c!= 'f' ...` better than `if (c != '}')`? Secondly, why do you first state that one less character has to be parsed in `%`-notation, then state that the parser needs to parse the next char to be able to see if it's valid? ...

Comment: @Agent_L: ... But if by "ending signal", you in fact meant a finite state machine or a big switch statement that falls through if there's no match, then there's not much of a difference between explicit format termination and implicit one, except that the %-one can only detect termination at the very end of a huge switch-statement, whereas the {}-one can check for `}` at the very beginning, which makes it more performant for the typical use case.  ...

Comment: @Agent_L: ... Furthermore, if a parser detects a potential terminator like `h`, but first needs to check more context to differentiate it from a non-terminator, than that's lookahead in parsing parlance. You need to _look ahead_ one character to determine whether to finalize this token or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Secure notes, C's `printf` function is inspired by BCPL's `writef` function.  And if you look at the wikipedia page for [BCPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL), it has an example that shows that BCPL `writef` also used `%` to introduce a format specifier.

So we can infer that C used `%` either because BCPL did, or for the same reasons that BCPL did.  My gut feeling is that it was simply that `%` is one of the least commonly used ASCII characters ... or so the authors thought.  It is also likely that they didn't spend a lot of time in weighing the various alternatives.  At the time, both BCPL and C were obscure languages, and the authors most likely had more important things to deal with.

However, there is a minor spanner in the works.  While C was inspired by BCPL, it is not entirely clear whether the C borrowed BCPL I/O libraries or the other way around.  I dimly recall that BCPL's I/O libraries went through a process of evolution about the time that the infix byte indexing operator was added to the language.  (Actually, I think I know who would know about that.)

Comment: "Actually, I think I know who would know about that" ... and? ... and?.. Don't just leave us with a cliff-hanger ...

Comment: @Mawg - Brian Knight probably would. Ian Wilson probably would.  Martin Richards definitely would.  HTH.

Answer (score 6):

The Wikipedia entry doesn't contain much historical information, not specific to `printf`, but to escape characters in general.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

> Early reference to the term "escape character" is found in Bob Bemer's
>   IBM technical publications. Apparently, it is he who invented this
>   mechanism, during his work on the ASCII character set.

My guess is: The backslash was already used for string literals and another character was needed for the format strings. Most likely they chose the character with the assumed least frequency of normal usage and occurrence.

BTW, another related article is linked there with a term I've nether heard before:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome

The article for `printf` has some more info snippets, but not about the reasons.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf

> C's variadic printf has its origins in BCPL's writef function.